# Laravel 5 php artisan create_users_table doesn't create template

Tags: php, database, migration, laravel-5

I am currently learning Laravel 5 and am experimenting with user logins and registration.

I used the command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users
```

the first time i ran this command it worked perfectly and created a migration file  with a selection of fields typically required for users, such as email, password etc.

I ran into some trouble and had to delete and recreate my migration files whilst troubleshooting. However now I am unable to get the same result when running the command. I just get the default:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUserTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

could someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is default migration file for users. I think you have not check after installing the laravel. Check the default migration file in github bellow

[default migration file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/database/migrations)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and see if it works for you

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users
```

Comment: sorry it was a typo, i used the correct command but did not get the right migration file as in question

Comment: had you used jeffrey way generators the first time?

Comment: jeffrey? i am not sure what you mean.

Comment: might be wrong but laravel does not include/scaffold email and password by default into your migrations when you create user. However you can include this package https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended                                                                                                  then use this command php artisan make:migration:schema create_users_table --schema="username:string, email:string:unique"

Answer (score 0):

I think i made a mistake and mistook the default migration files included in laravel with the ones i generated.

The CreateUsersTable is a predefined migration file that gives all the standard fields a user record would require.

Thanks